# trying to develop code for user login in c++

Tags: c++

I am working on a project in which i have to set up user login. User data is stored in a file in a class structure. 
This is my function for login:

```
bool check_login(int n, string pass)
{
    bool found = false;
    account ac;
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("final.dat",ios::binary);
    if(!infile)
    {
        cout<<"File could not be open !! Press any Key...";
        return false;
    }
    while(!infile.eof() && found==false)
    {
        infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&ac), sizeof(account));
        if(ac.retacno()==n)
        {
            if(pass.compare(ac.retpassword())==0)
            found=true;
            return found;
          }
    }
    infile.close();
    return found;
}

class account
{
        int acno;
        string password;
        string name;
        string address;
        char sex;
        string phonenumber;
    public:
        void create_account();  //function to get data from user
        void show_account() const;  //function to show data on screen
        void modify();  //function to add new data
        void withdraw(int,int); //function to accept amount and subtract from balance amount
        void donate(int,int);   //function to accept amount and add to balance amount
        void report() const;    //function to show data in tabular format
        int retacno() const;    //function to return account number
        string retpassword() const; //function to return password
};
```

This poses a runtime error - process exited with return value 255. in dev-c++

Comment: Where is the `main()` ?

Comment: Could you show the definition of `account`, please?

Comment: the cast of account to char* is likely invalid.

Comment: @Abhishek it is better you edit your question then add unreadable code as a comment.

Comment: Please edit the question instead of posting the code in comments.

Comment: Never try to write a `class` to file - most of them are not `POD` and you are likely to run into padding issues if they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This here

```
infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&ac), sizeof(account));
```

will not work well for a class. You need to add code to serialize and deserialize your account instances. As it is now you read in all the stuff from the file into the account instance without running any constructors of the members e.g. string.

To serialize/deserialize you can for instance override the `>>` and `<<` operators.